# How do I store images in an array for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, image, submit

I was wondering if anyone knew if it is possible and how you would go about storing an image in an array. I am fairly new to JavaScript so if you do know how to do it could you walk through the syntax and explain how you did it. I have tried using locally stored photos as well as image URLs from the internet. I want to display the photos when certain conditions are met and a button is pushed. I am trying to make a movie suggestion website that will show an array of images when a genre is selected and the button is pushed. I know my code isn't close to complete but any push in the right direction would be most appreciated.

This is how I've tried to store the images in an array and it isn't working

var images = ['github-logo.png', 'linkedin-logo.png', 'gmail.png']

Comment: how were you using the array of images?

Comment: If you just want to store the URL to the pics, then you are on the right track. If you wanted to pre-load the images using JavaScript then you need to create an array of image elements.

Comment: I was using multiple arrays to store images correlating to a genre of movie and then when a user selects a genre and hits submit the correlating array of images was supposed to pop up underneath the form as suggestions

Comment: How would I create an array of image elements?

Comment: var img = document.createElement('img'); 
img.src = 'github-logo.png'; 
document.getElementById('body').appendChild(img);

Comment: something like that in a function for each array element. Then append to an html element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an array like below:

```
var pics = {
    "genre1":["pic1.jpg", "pic2.jpg", "pic3.jpg"],
    "genre2":["pic4.jpg", "pic5.jpg", "pic6.jpg"],
    "genre3":["pic7.jpg", "pic8.jpg", "pic9.jpg"]
};
```

Then you can get the related pics for a particular genre like below:

```
var picarray = pics.genre1;
```

Or

```
var picarray = pics["genre1"];
```

Comment: How would I go about posting the selected array to the body of the HTML document?